# Looking for the right word to express my "skin in game" when talking about someone else

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

For everyone who has a loved one in the fight, prayers are going out for each and everyone! Lord, keep them ALL safe and bring them home! This man is my __________ in the fight.

Comment: It would be my *Hero* in the fight but I think you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 1):

There are two closely related idioms, variations of each which can be referenced in the question.

The first is [*skin in the game*](https://www.definitions.net/definition/skin+in+the+game):

> [Definitions]
>   A stake; something at risk, especially with regard to money and investments.

The second, which has the same meaning but which a variation of can be used as a drop-in to the example sentence, is [**have a dog in this fight**](https://www.definitions.net/definition/HAVE%20A%20DOG%20IN%20THIS%20FIGHT):

> [Definitions]
>   To have a personal stake in an issue.

Perhaps used both metaphorically (because it's an idiom) *and* literally in an analogical sense (because it's also talking about an actual person) the example sentence could include the following variation:

> For everyone who has a loved one in the fight, prayers are going out for each and everyone! Lord, keep them ALL safe and bring them home! This man is my *dog in the fight*.